# C# call to DataLakeDirectoryClient.CreateSubDirectoryAsync creating sub directory and zero byte file with same name

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm not sure why, but calling this `DataLakeDirectoryClient.CreateSubDirectoryAsync` function creates a sub directory and a zero byte file of the same name.  I only want it to create the sub directory.  Note: I can see the zero byte file in Azure portal's Storage Browser, but not in Azure Storage Explorer.

`myDirectoryClient` is of type `Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.DataLakeDirectoryClient`

```
var mySubDirectoryClient = await myDirectoryClient.CreateSubDirectoryAsync("my_sub_dir");
```

Now I have the zero byte file, but no directory.
Next, I upload a file to the sub directory. `fileName`, `mylocalFilePath` are set elsewhere with valid values.  The new file creation and upload works fine.

```
var newFileClient = mySubDirectoryClient.GetFileClient(fileName);
await using var uploadFs = File.OpenRead(mylocalFilePath);
var response = newFileClient.UploadAsync(uploadFs).Result;
```

Now I have the zero byte file, and the sub directory, and the file in the sub directory. Files/folders in picture have a different name (not `"my_sub_dir"`), but they were created the same way.
[image]

Is there a reason I have the extra zero byte file? Can I prevent this? Or do I just need to delete it afterwards? Or would deleting it be an issue?

I somewhat understand why the empty file is created, which I believe is that it doesn't treat it like a directory until it contains a file.  Kind of like how when you delete all of the files in a folder the folder disappears.  I'd like to create the direct

Edit: Above code is snippets... I am uploading the entire function below, for clarity.  This is a recursive function meant to copy all the files and subdirectories from a directory.  It downloads a file locally, then uploads it to another location on a datalake, but as far as my question is concerned, the only code that should matter is in the `if(path.IsDirectory??false)`

```
async Task CopyDirectory(DataLakeDirectoryClient sourceDirectoryClient, DataLakeDirectoryClient targetDirectoryClient)
{
  var pathPages = sourceDirectoryClient.GetPathsAsync();
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  await foreach (var page in pathPages.AsPages())
  {
    foreach (var path in page.Values)
    {
      var fileName = path.Name.Split("/").Last();
      if (path.IsDirectory??false)
      {
        var sourceSubDirectoryClient = sourceDirectoryClient.GetSubDirectoryClient(fileName);
        var targetSubDirectoryClient = await targetDirectoryClient.CreateSubDirectoryAsync(fileName);
        await CopyDirectory(sourceSubDirectoryClient, targetSubDirectoryClient, targetFileSystemClient);
        //this only returns one path that is a directory per directory, not one zero byte file and one directory                        
        //var x = targetDirectoryClient.GetPathsAsync();
        //await foreach (var y in x.AsPages())
        //{
        //    foreach (var z in y.Values)
        //    {
        //        Console.WriteLine(z);
        //    }
        //}
      }
      else if (true) //fileName.Contains("2023")) //filter here
      {
        var downloadPath = localTempPath + fileName;
        var sourceFileClient = sourceDirectoryClient.GetFileClient(fileName);
        var properties = await sourceFileClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await FileDownloader.DownloadFileAsync(sourceFileClient, downloadPath))
                            .ContinueWith((result) => FileUploader.UploadFileAsync(targetDirectoryClient, properties, downloadPath))
                            .ContinueWith(async (result) => await DeleteFilesAsync(downloadPath)) // this cleans up the local file
                        );
      }
    }
  }
  Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to have a folder and a file with the same name.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the reply.  That's what I thought, too.  I called the function `myDirectoryClient.GetPathsAsync()` and it only returned the sub directory.  Very odd to see one block blob file and one directory of the same name in storage browser.  Maybe it's a display issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an explanation of "why it didn't work", rather than an answer.
The root cause is that the storage account I was writing to was not Data Lake Storage.  It was a plain old Blob Storage.  It was not my account; I was just trying to move some files from my ADLS Gen 2 to their storage account.
The code I had worked when I tried to create sub directories on my own ADLS Gen 2 account.
Hopefully it can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

**`Before creating main and sub folder:`**

[image]

To create Main Folder and Sub Folder with same name you can follow below **`code`**:

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;


string constring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwikst;AccountKey=laUfWt+AStx9qP7Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
string conname = "rithwik";
string folderPath = "/myfolder/myfolder";


var rithclient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(constring, conname);
rithclient.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
Console.WriteLine("Folder and subfolder created Rithwik Bojja.");
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

If you want to create a Sub Folder  in Existing Folder with same name follow below **`code`**:

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;


string constring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwikst;AccountKey=laUfW9qP7Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
string conname = "rithwik";
string folderPath = "/myfold";
string subFolderPath = $"{folderPath}/myfold"; 

var rithclient = new DataLakeFileSystemClient(constring, conname);
rithclient.CreateDirectory(subFolderPath);
Console.WriteLine("Subfolder created Rithwik.");
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

This is how I create folders and subfolders in Storage account **`without`** getting extra files with 0 bytes.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like you tried to use the `DeltaLakeFileSystemClient` to create the directory and the child directory at the same time.  I'm  not doing it that way, because I am doing other things at the folder level.  I will upload my entire function to the end of the question.  Original code was just snippets.

Comment: No, at the second part of my answer, you can see i created subfolder also under header  **If you want to create a Sub Folder in Existing Folder with same name follow below code**, check it it solves your problem.

Comment: I tried to make another folder like you had, and it's still making the 0 byte file display in the container.  I don't know why.  Also, my goal was not to create a sub folder with the same name.